# How to have scroll when zooming canvas stage

Tags: canvas, scrollbar, kineticjs

I am having a designer tool developed in canvas using KineticJs library.
Everything working fine except that when I press Zoom in/out and it sets the zoom on stage to 2x then I would need scrollbars both vertical and horizontal.
I have tried giving css overflow to the stage itself and for container as well but does not work. How could I manage doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track...

Make the stage-canvas larger than the div containing the stage. Then set overflow:hidden on the container.

If you want to allow panning by the scrollbars then your stage must be larger than the containing viewport or you will "run out of canvas".

```js
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 740,
  height: 463
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {

  var kImg = new Kinetic.Image({
    image: image,
    id: 99,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 740,
    height: 463,
    draggable: false
  });
  layer.add(kImg);
  layer.draw();
}
image.src = "http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/Colorful-New-York-City.jpg";
```

```css
#wrapper {
    overflow:scroll;
    width:300px;
    height:350px;
    border:2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kineticjs/5.2.0/kinetic.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi markE! Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it's not a solution in my case. I have a 464x650px canvas for designing an A4 sticker page, here's the url: http://www.resolution-studio.ro/new/sticker/designer/ . I have a zoomIn tool on the right, which sets the stage scale attribute to 2. When doing this the first quarter of the A4 will be visible, but not the rest. Thats what I need scroll for. Theoretically I need it inside the canvas I think. Am I wrong?

Comment: If I chose your solution then I would need to use 4 times bigger stage (2x width and 2x height) and set the overflow of the canvas container to hidden. Then when I press the zoomIn I would need to set the stage scale to 2 and set the overflow of the container to scroll. I think that woulc work, but I'm affraid of one thing: things will be more complicated when I will be requested to do multiple level of zooms.